# Need help troubleshooting a failing Rspec test - Argument error: Comparison of Date with nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec

I'm trying to troubleshoot a test in Rspec.  My program code works as expected, but there's a problem in my test code.  The relevant rspec contains:

```
it "is invalid without a date" do
  appointment = FactoryGirl.build(:appointment, date: "")      
  appointment.valid?
  expect(appointment.errors[:date]).to include("can't be blank")
end
```

Rspec generates the following error:

```
Failure/Error: appointment.valid?
 ArgumentError:
   comparison of Date with nil failed
```

It appears the error is caused by my leaving the date field blank to test the scenario (i.e., invalid without a date). How do I use Rspec to properly test this scenario if setting date to nil or leaving it blank generates an error?  I researched the error message, but didn't find a solution.  What's the best approach to deal with the problem?

Comment: Can you post the relevant parts of your Appointment model (validations, etc)?

Comment: Dylan - my Appointment model contains the following date related validation: validates :date, :starts_at, :ends_at, :member, :trainer, presence: true

Comment: And there's no other code in your model related to the `:date` field like a before_save or before_validation filter?

Comment: No before_save or before_validation filters. However, I do have this validation which scopes to the date field:
validates :starts_at, :ends_at, :overlap => {
    :exclude_edges => ["starts_at", "ends_at"],
    :scope => "date",
    :scope => "starts_at",    
    :scope => "trainer_id"    
    }
Is this relevant? I didn't include it initially, because I didn't think it was pertinent.

Comment: My apologies! in my last post, I neglected to include one other date related validation. I "commented out" that  validation and the Rspec passed.  Here's the validation, which may be giving Rspec a problem:
validate :past_dated_appointment  

private

  def past_dated_appointment 
    if Date.current > self.date 
    errors.add(:date, "can't be in the past")         
    end
  end

Answer (score 1):

Your validation method is comparing a `Date` to `nil`, hence the error. I can't explain where the empty string you're passing in is getting coerced into `nil`, but you can't compare a `Date` to a string either. You need to either rework your validation method to accommodate the full range of potential `date` values and/or put additional validations in front it (e.g. `presence: true`). Once you do that, your test should be able to run.

Comment: To Dylan & Peter:  Thanks to both of you ... I decided to discard my exiting method and use a validation helper from the Validate_Timeliness gem.  Here's what I did:
validates_date :date, :on => :create, :on_or_after => :today
This change works in my program and Rspec is happy:  the previously failing test, now passes! I appreciate both of your responses, because they helped expand my understanding of Rails, esp. how nil and Date objects work. I will give both answers a point. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

It's because of your other validation:

```
validate :past_dated_appointment

private 

def past_dated_appointment
  if Date.current > self.date
    errors.add(:date, "can't be in the past")
  end
end
```

You should probably first check that the date is present:

```
if self.date && Date.current > self.date
```